# Как отсортировать массив по переданным параметрам

Tags: php

у меня есть массив следующего типа

```
  2 => "dcbd1b"
  4 => "d438e6"
  5 => "119f28"
  1 => "e91f1f"
```

в get запросе приходят ключи этого массива. Подскажите как мне сортировать этот массив что бы впереди стояли ключи равные значением из get параметрам.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//$skey=$_GET['key'];
$skey='4';
//4 допустим

 $data=array('2' => "dcbd1b",
  '4' => "d438e6",
  '5' => "119f28",
  '1' => "e91f1f");
 print_r($data);
echo "<br>";

$value=$data[$skey];
unset($data[$skey]);
$newdata[$skey]=$value;
$data1 = $newdata + $data;


print_r($data1);
?>
```